# Compress Classes of DAO layer

Tags: php, design-patterns, orm, doctrine

I'm work with a MVC application which can be considered big or medium, it involves hundred of functionalities and more of 400 tables on MYSQL. As a ORM tool we adopt through dependence injection the Doctrine, and also adopted the DAO (Data Access Object) pattern for storing queries for each class of Entity, in other words, each table have a Entity class, and each Entity class have a DAO class.

I don't know if this is normal, but the problem is which the DAO classes are getting to big, in some already have over 30 methods where each one represents a query or business rule.

We are trying create methods more generally and parametrized way possible, furthermore, all DAO classes are subclasses of the AbstractDAO class, which already implements and offers generic methods as insert, update, find, list and others.

What you suggest for me? Some technical, pattern or tool for trying to compact my code more, or at least organize it better?

Comment: @tereško the database of my application is actually a little legacy, because we started with a PHP structured application some years ago. Either way our application is also very large, because your line of business is very large, comparing it with an ERP.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to say without looking at the code and the kind of queries you are doing.

An alternative I like to the DAO approach is to have a class per query, this should allow you to have some behaviour on those queries that can reduce the number of classes you get in the end. Of course, in the worst case if you have 500 queries, you will end with 500 new classes, which might be far from ideal.

From experience what tends to happen is that many of those 500 queries have many things in common, same query but an extra parameter, same query but paging, etc. If this matches your case, you can make your queries be a builder to reuse most of the code. Also you can move certain common things to a base query class etc.

Another advantage is that when you need to add new queries, you just keep adding classes and don't need to touch your already big and monolithic DAOs

See this question I asked some time ago, is for c# but the same concept should carry over to php: [Modeling NHibernate queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991416/modeling-nhibernate-queries)